# GROUP_CONCAT on LEFT JOIN generates groups against NULL

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I'm trying to use a LEFT JOIN in conjunction with a GROUP_CONCAT but not getting the expected results.

Two simple tables:

weather_alerts:

```
id | user_id | resort_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 1       | 3
4  | 1       | 5
```

weather_users

```
id | email
1  | me@me.com
```

The query:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(wa.resort_id) AS resort_ids, wu.email FROM weather_alerts wa LEFT JOIN weather_users wu ON wa.id = wu.user_id GROUP BY wu.email`

Instead of generating:

```
email            resort_ids
me@me.com        1,2,3,5
```

I get:

```
email            resort_ids
NULL             2,3,5
me@me.com        1
```

I suspect this is an issue with the JOIN rather than the CONCAT.

Comment: To my way of thinking, there is no problem in MySQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or indeed CONCAT) is part of the solution. Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer if that's available.

Comment: I am getting the right results with similar query - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1c6c1/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your LEFT JOIN needs improvement.

```
create table weather_alerts (id int, user_id int, resort_id int);
insert into weather_alerts values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (4, 1, 5);

create table weather_users (id int, email varchar(100));
insert into weather_users values (1, 'me@me.com');
```

Query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(wa.resort_id ORDER BY wa.resort_id) AS resort_ids, wu.email 
FROM weather_alerts wa 
LEFT JOIN weather_users wu ON wa.user_id = wu.id 
GROUP BY wu.email
```

Notice that you are joining on `wa.id = wu.user_id`. The join should be on `wa.user_id = wu.id`

Result

```
| resort_ids |     email |
|------------|-----------|
|    1,2,3,5 | me@me.com |
```